# How to put more than one multi-word variable on discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

```py
@client.command()
async def embed (ctx, title, comma, *, description): 
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1) 
  embed = discord.Embed(title = title, description = description)
  embed.set_footer(text="An embed")
  embed.set_author(name = f'{ctx.author.name} says'  , icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url )
  await ctx.send (embed = embed)
```

Here, the title should be multiple words and the description must be multiple words. Right now, the title is one word only and the description is multiple words. How do I make it so that both can be multiple words?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. How's the parser supposed to know what is the title and what is the description?

Comment: @Łukasz Kwieciński
but I have seperated them with a comma. An example of what I want is the 'pls cheating' command in dank memer

Comment: `comma` is not used in your code. What is the usage here?

Comment: Take it all as a string and split it by the comma.

Comment: You could also use a more complex method with `wait_for("message")` and then ask for the different inputs one after another (title, description etc.).

Comment: @Łukasz Kwieciński  uh i dunno what that means

Comment: Take the whole text (title and description) as a single string, then inside the command split the string by the comma.

Answer (score 1):

To take multiple words inside your argument, simply put all of the words into your argument and split it with a comma.

```py
@client.command()
async def embed(ctx, *, args):
  title = args.split(',')[0] # Gets the title by finding index 0
  description = args.split(',')[1]

  embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=description)
  
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Briefly, what this code does is, it splits the `args` argument into a list using a comma, get the appropriate index for `title` and `description` and sends it in a `discord.Embed()`.